# Spring boot service method returns page of interfaces

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's suppose that I have an interface `Stuff` like this:

```
public interface Stuff {
  Long getId();

  String getName();
}
```

and I have implemented this interface as `StuffEntity`:

```
@Entity
public class StuffEntity implements Stuff {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  protected Long id;
  protected String name;

  // constructors, getters (implement interface methods), setters, ...
}
```

and I have a service interface `StuffService`:

```
public interface StuffService {
  Page<Stuff> getStuff(Pageable pageable);
}
```

implemented as `StuffServiceImpl`:

```
@Service
public class StuffServiceImpl implements StuffService {
  @Autowired
  private StuffEntityRepository repository;

  @Overrride
  public Page<Stuff> getStuff(Pageable pageable) {
    Page<StuffEntity> stuffEntityPage = repository.findAll(pageable);
    return new PageImpl<>(stuffEntityPage.getContent().stream()
      .map(Stuff.class::cast)
      .collect(
        Collectors.toList()), 
        stuffEntityPage.getPageable(), 
        stuffEntityPage.getTotalElements()
      );
}
```

I don't like casting here and creating new instance of `PageImpl`, so I tried something like this:

```
public interface StuffService {
  Page<? extends Stuff> getStuff(Pageable pageable);
}
```

```
@Service
public class StuffServiceImpl implements StuffService {
  @Autowired
  private StuffEntityRepository repository;

  @Overrride
  public Page<? extends Stuff> getStuff(Pageable pageable) {
    return repository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

As I've already said, I don't like casting and creating new `PageImpl` instance in my service class, but I like how my code looks cleaner that way. The other approach does not need casting or creating new `PageImpl` instance in my service class, but I am little worried about service's client side, because now I return wildcard instead of an interface.

Which approach do you think is better?

Comment: "I am little worried about service's client side" Why? 2nd one is objectively better.

Comment: I presume that Page is [Spring's version](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html)? Or if not, it's at least read-only i.e. you cannot add items to a page? In which case, [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) applies. It's a producer, so `? extends` is the correct choice.

Comment: I am worried about client's side because now it has to handle wildcard. But yes, returned `Page` is supposed to be read-only. Also, it will never be a collection of multiple types of `Stuff`, but I might have `public class StuffOtherImpl implements Stuff` and `public class StuffServiceOtherImpl implements StuffService` which will return `Page` of `StuffOtherImpl` .

Comment: The real problem is that you are defining interfaces for your entities, this is generally something to avoid.

Comment: @M.Deinum beeeecause...?

Comment: I noted the same thing. This is using an interface to "mask" an entity instead of properly transforming the entity to a DTO with the required data. Difference being that with DTOs the entities never escape the DAL, while here you're putting a coat on it and saying "nobody will notice". Lose the interface, return entities and map them to DTOs (e.g. in façade) and *this* particular problem will disappear (and you'll have a more robust architecture).

Answer (score 0):

It is always good practice to not use wildcard type as return type.

> It is highly recommended not to use wildcard types as return types.
> Because the type inference rules are fairly complex it is unlikely the
> user of that API will know how to use it correctly.
>
> Let's take the example of method returning a "List<? extends Animal>".
> Is it possible on this list to add a Dog, a Cat, ... we simply don't
> know. And neither does the compiler, which is why it will not allow
> such a direct use. The use of wildcard types should be limited to
> method parameters.
>
> This rule raises an issue when a method returns a wildcard type.

[Source](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1452)

Comment: Link only answers aren't good answers, and charity upvotes aren't good upvotes.

Comment: @Kayaman Telling people how to use their votes is waste of time and energy, people will do what they want

Comment: Disagree with this answer, even though it's from an "authoritative" source like Sonar. The whole justification seems to be that you cannot add to a list. Well, what if it's not a Collection? OP has a Page, and it's not possible to add to one. Seems like PECS applies. I disagree that it's "*unlikely the user of that API will know how to use it correctly*"